# Not able to find /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I have installed Nginx server at my cloud space checked by ip it is showing proper page.
Now I have also a apache Tomcat8 on port `8080`
I want to redirect my port `80` traffic to `8080`
for that I am following this tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/nginx/nginx-apache-tomcat-configuration-example/
My problem is I am not getting the path
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

I am checing my tomcat application with IP address
How to add nxg config detail

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is the path given to the default website for Debian based systems.  They are usually links to files contained `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d` is a path used in most configurations including Debian derivatives like Ubuntu and other distro's like CentOS etc.

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the main configuration file that includes all **conf** files from one or both of those directories.

You can usually place a configuration file ending in `.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

So with that knowledge.  Create a conf file with a configuration like the following:

So create a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/tomcat.conf` containing a configuration like:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     yourdomain.com;

  proxy_cache one;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  }
}
```

Note: the `proxy_set_headers` are useful for logging and apps that need to identify the real client.  In theory you can extract the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header to use as the real address for the address of the client in your app or tomcat logs.  Otherwise the client will always appear to be the address of the proxy server itself.

Comment: `server_name     yourdomain.com;` should be like  `server_name     abcc.com;` or  `server_name     www.abcd.com;`

Comment: done this step onening browser is not redirection to tomcat

Comment: @xrcwrn - Is tomcat listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080 or an macine IP port 8080 ?  If it's listening on your local machine IP, then that is why it's not working.  Change it to listen on 127.0.0.1

Comment: Verify tomcat works first.   point your browser at 127.0.0.1:8080,  If it doesn't come up, don't blame it on nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the proxy module in Nginx. Something like this should work:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;
  server_name           yourserver.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    include proxy_params
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847771/configure-nginx-with-proxy-pass

Comment: on which file I will write above content as in mentioned tutorial It is givent to write content in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` but I am not getting file I dont have `sites-enabled` folder. I am only Ip address

Comment: done above but it is not redirecting to tomcat

Answer (score 1):

You should start with checking compiled-in settings for nginx with nginx -V. It should point you to main configuration file, --conf-path= flag.

All other files should be included with "include" directive in nginx. If you want you can add server {} directive to main configuration file.